# How to play two videos from the terminal (loop, fullscreen), dual screen on the raspberry pi 4b?

Tags: pi-4, omxplayer

i'm a PiNoob :) who can help me?

How can I play two videos (in sync) on the raspberry pi 4b? I'm using omx player. I need to combine the following lines:

```
omxplayer --display=2 --loop /home/pi/Desktop/front.mp4
omxplayer --display=7 --loop /home/pi/Desktop/back.mp4
```

Is there a way to run these commands at the same time, maybe with a script? I have no idea :)

Comment: can you run two videos on one screen?

Comment: I want to run it on two screens, HDMI 0 and HDMI 1.

Comment: if you cannot run two videos on one screen, then you won't be able to run on two screens either ... make sure that the omxplayer allows two videos to be played

Comment: I can run the videos on two screens, when i run the command "omxplayer --display=2 --loop /home/pi/Desktop/front.mp4;
omxplayer --display=7 --loop /home/pi/Desktop/back.mp4" it runs the videos on the two screens but after each other. The second video will start when I've closed the first one. I want them to play at the same time

Answer (score 2):

Provided the CPU can handle it, you need to replace the ";" between the commands with a "&" - this will put the first job in the background and immediately execute the second.

Answer (score 1):

It works if you disable keys, e.g.

```
# run the first video in the background with key inputs disabled
omxplayer --no-keys --display=2 --loop /home/pi/Desktop/back.mp4 &

# run the second video normally
omxplayer --display=7 --loop /home/pi/Desktop/back.mp4
```

Comment: On my pi with a .mov video, my second omxplayer is just dying with "have a nice day".  Any thoughts?

Comment: @Fiid hard to tell. does it work if you play the .mov video with omxplayer by itself?